# Unable to edit restricted group policy

Tags: windows, group-policy

I enabled a something in group policies so that only a selected list of applications would open, in that list was only "chrome.exe".

I intended for it to apply to only that account however it was set for the whole computer.

When I try to open "edit group policy", it says it is restricted.

My Question:
How do I access "edit group policy" or something similar so I can access my other applications again?

Comment: where you modified the changes?which os version?is it domain based gp or user based gp?kindly brief over it

Comment: @BlueBerry-Vignesh4303 In order of appearance: I don't know what you mean by that. The version is windows 10. It's local GP, that's all I know.

Comment: I've edited your title to remove the fake tags (we have actual tags) but I'm not sure if I got the right meaning of your question. You should be able to edit your question to fix it if you wish. It might be worth you taking the [tour] to see how things work around here.

Comment: What you may do to start is confirm what GP settings are being applied and confirm the exact one you changed using the command line tool that's run from an elevated command prompt perhaps with a similar syntax of: `gpresult /H C:\users\user\desktop\GPResults.html`. Once you do that, open the HTML file in the location you save it and you may have to select the SHOW ALL option to expand all GP settings, and then find the one that appears you changed from there and then tell which setting you changed that you see there. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456989.aspx

Comment: Once you see the setting you changed that you suspect is causing this, please disclose that information so people don't have to guess what you changed that is causing your problem. Since you enabled "something" in GP, it'd be best to tell us what that was which you changed so we can potentially give advice how to undo that, etc. some way.